Linking to the result of hx-target
I have a webapp that uses HTMX for doing the dynamic stuff I want. The frontpage has a search field. When the search field triggers, it uses a div below it to render the result:
<form hx-get="/search" hx-target="#data">
<input type="search" name="q" hx-trigger="keyup[keyCode==13]"/>
</form>

<div id="data"></div>

This works fine. My /search API endpoint returns an HTML table which is rendered into #data.
However, I also want the search to be sharable, so I add hx-push-url to the form:
<form hx-get="/search" hx-target="#data" hx-push-url="true">

This updates the address bar nicely with /search?q=foobar but when I open that URL directly I just get the HTML table (obviously). What is the right way to do this?

I solved this in the backend by looking for the Hx-Request header. If it is "true" it means the request was initiated by using the search form, otherwise the page was opened using a direct URL.
I'm using Go, so in my case all I had to do was check for the header and render the according template:
templateName := "search.html" // contains complete HTML page
if isHxRequest(r) {
    templateName = "resulttable" // a separate template defined with "define"
}

// render `templateName` here


I'd add the contents of the isHxRequest() function, so others can see how that header is checked.  You might also try using the same template with an hx-select to select only the table, rather than writing two templates.
